# How to compare the given integer with possible roots

Tags: java, input, integer

I could not name the question in the best way... My aim is to write a program that takes `integer` n from user. Then compare with the third power of two integers a and b.
If a^3 + b^3 is smaller than or equal to the given input, I want to print out every single possible calculation to the user.

My code is as follows:

```
        System.out.println("Hi. Please insert an integer: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = input.nextInt();
        double root = Math.cbrt(n);
        int rootInt = (int) root;

        for (int i = 0; i < rootInt; i++){ 
            for (int j = 0; j < rootInt; j++){

                if ((Math.pow(i, 3)) + (Math.pow(j, 3)) <= n){

                    double t = (Math.pow(i, 3) + (Math.pow(j, 3)));
                    int totalInt = (int) t;

                    System.out.println(i + "^3" + " + " + j + "^3" + " = " + totalInt );

                } else {

                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

When I run this and give an input as 30, it prints

```
0^3 + 0^3 = 0
0^3 + 2^3 = 8
2^3 + 0^3 = 8
2^3 + 2^3 = 16
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increase `j` and `i` twice. That's why you test only the even values for `i`, `j`.

If you want to correct the code, remove the `i++, j++` from the end and use only the increments from the 2 `for`s.